# Postfix Double Slash Notation with Multiple Parameters

Tags: syntax, core-language

**Examples**

A convenient shorthand that I use frequently is the "double slash" notation to string commands together.  For example, I can write:

```
x - 1 + x^2 //TraditionalForm
```

And receive back:

```
x^2 + x - 1
```

Or another example:

```
(x - 1)(x + 2) //Expand //TraditionalForm
```

Yields:

```
x^2 + x - 2
```

---

However, I have never been able to find a way to input *multiple* arguments into a function using this notation.  That is, I cannot call something like:

```
x^2 + 9x + 5, 3 //PolynomialMod
```

Obviously the above can easily be written as:

```
PolynomialMod[x^2 + 9x + 5, 3]
```

(but what's the fun in that?)

**Question**

Is there a way to input multiple parameters using the shorthand postfix operator?

See also:
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Postfix.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A lot of functions in MMA have default values for Optional Arguments, for Example `Flatten`. It can take `Flatten[expr]` which means `Flatten[expr, Infinity]`

Some functions don't have such option and you need to feed the Optional Arguments but you can go around by building your own function

for your example, you can do this kind of trick like this:

```
f[expr_, n_: 3] := PolynomialMod[expr, n]
```

now

```
x^2 + 9 x + 5 // f
2 + x^2
```

In this case you will have fixed value for Optional Arguments which is 3 and if you need to use this method with other value than 3 you need to change 3 in the definition of f above. However, an easy way to do it is as follows:

```
x^2 + 9 x + 5 // PolynomialMod[#, 3] &
```

Comment: I'd say the last line is the definite answer to the question (i.e. using a pure function with multiple arguments).

Comment: The last line is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @YvesKlett, it was the definitive answer until V10 operator forms.

Comment: @alancalvitti why not post another answer to that regard?

Comment: @YvesKlett, I'll post it as a question as op form doesn't currentyl support variadics for example. I don't have a ready answer.

Answer (score 6):

[Algohi's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61481/8253) is the most appropriate if one of the function's arguments is primary and the others secondary. However, you can get closer to the syntax that you suggested in your question using

```
{x^2 + 9 x + 5, 3} // Apply @ PolynomialMod
```

which works in version 10 using the operator form of `Apply`.

Or, to include earlier versions, you could define your own "postfix" operator like

```
Colon[list_, f_] := f @@ list
```

Then you can write

```
{x^2 + 9x + 5, 3} ∶ PolynomialMod
```

That's the `\[Colon]` character, also entered as <kbd>Esc</kbd>`:`<kbd>Esc</kbd>, or you could use any other infix operator with no built-in meaning.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `Sequence`

```
PolynomialMod[x^2 + 9 x + 5, 3]

PolynomialMod@Sequence[x^2 + 9 x + 5, 3]

Sequence[x^2 + 9 x + 5, 3] // PolynomialMod
2 + x^2
```

all produce the same output.

Works with any function

```
Sequence[i, {i, 10}] // Table
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do (but only for two arguments)

> x^2 + 9x + 5 ~ PolynomialMod ~ 3

Comment: Using the infix notation is an interesting idea, but as you pointed out, it only seems to work on two arguments.  And it is a side-step to being able to do this with postfix notation, which is what I want.

Comment: While there are several huge infixionados around and infix is useful stuff , this is not actually answering the question...

Comment: Interesting, but hard to read, as infixes tend to be, except perhaps in the case of `Join`: `a ~ Join ~ b`.

Comment: @asterix314 ... well...  1+1 *is* easy to parse :-)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can use new Mathematica operator forms (V10+)

```
{-5, -3, -1, 2, 4, 6} // SortBy[Abs]
```

> {-1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6}

Comment: But operator forms have similar limitation as `//` in terms of handling variable number of arguments.