# How can I mix // with a function of two arguments?

Tags: functions, syntax, pure-function

I often find myself using `//` when playing around with expressions, but it is always cumbersome to have to switch to the full notation just to apply a function of two arguments.

```
(x+1)^3
(x+1)^3 // Expand
Collect[(x+1)^3 // Expand, x]
```

I found that there is one way to do this using a pure function, though I'm not sure if this is the best way

```
(x+1)^3 // Expand // Collect[#, x]&
```

Comment: I swear someone asked almost this exact question a couple days ago. Let me see if I can find it...

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61479/postfix-double-slash-notation-with-multiple-parameters

Comment: @kguler: LOL we both typed it at the exact same time :)